# Creating temp file vs process substitution vs variable expansion?

Tags: linux, variable, process-substitution

If I am doing something like

1. creating temporary file

   ```
   some process generating output > temp_file
   cat  temp_file
   ```
2. process substitution:

   ```
   cat <(some process generating output)
   ```
3. another way :

   ```
   cat <<<(some process generating output)
   ```

I have some doubts regarding these:

1. Is there any limit on data output size of process substitution`<()` `>()` or variable expansion
   `<<<()`
2. Which among these is the fastest or is there a way to do it faster?

My ulimit command output is :

```
bash-3.00$ ulimit -a
core file size        (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size         (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size             (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                    (-n) 256
pipe size          (512 bytes, -p) 10
stack size            (kbytes, -s) 8480
cpu time             (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes            (-u) 8053
virtual memory        (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Comment: i am not sure about the terminology for <<<() so gave it the term variable expansion.please bear:-)

Comment: <<< is called a HERESTRING, similar to a HEREDOC. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document

Comment: `<<<(...)` should probably be `<<<"$(...)"`, which makes it a combination of a _here-string_ (`<<<`, as stated) and a _command substitution_ (`$(...)`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash process substitution in the form of `<(cmd)` and `>(cmd)` is implemented with named pipes if the system supports them. The command `cmd` is run with its input/output connected to a pipe. When you run e.g. `cat <(sleep 10; ls)` you can find the created pipe under the directory `/proc/pid_of_cat/fd`. This named pipe is then passed as an argument to the current command (`cat`).

The buffer capacity of a pipe can be estimated with a tricky usage of `dd` command which sends zero data to the standard input of `sleep` command (which does nothing). Apparently, the process will sleep some time so the buffer will get full:

```
(dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 | sleep 999) &
```

Give it a second and then send `USR1` signal to the `dd` process:

```
pkill -USR1 dd
```

This makes the process to print out I/O statistics:

```
65537+0 records in
65536+0 records out
65536 bytes (66 kB) copied, 8.62622 s, 7.6 kB/s
```

In my test case, the buffer size is `64kB` (`65536B`).

How do you use `<<<(cmd)` expansion? I'm aware of  it's a variation of here documents which is expanded and passed to the command on its standard input.

Hopefully, I shed some light on the question about size. Regarding speed, I'm not so sure but I would assume that both methods can deliver similar throughput.

Comment: Nice writeup. The OP probably meant `<<<"$(...)"` rather than `<<<(...)`. Here's an automated one-liner that works on Linux and BSD/macOS for measuring the pipe buffer size (outputs results after 2 secs.): `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 | sleep 999 & sleep 2 && pkill -INT -P $$ -x dd`

Answer (score 7):

`<(cmd)` is a `ksh` feature also found nowadays in `zsh` and `bash` called *process substitution*.

On systems that support `/dev/fd/n` or `/proc/self/fd/n`, it's implemented with pipes and when not with temporary named pipes. In any case, it's a form of pipe that is an interprocess communication mechanism.

```
cmd1 <(cmd2)
```

Can be written (with normal pipes):

```
{ cmd2 4<&- | 3<&0 <&4 4<&- cmd1 /dev/fd/3; } 4<&0
```

Or (with named pipes):

```
mkfifo /tmp/named_pipe
cmd2 > /tmp/named_pipe & cmd1 /tmp/named_pipe
```

That is, both commands are started simultaneously and communicate with a pipe. You would usually use `cmd2 | cmd1` for that, but process substitution are typically for those cases where `cmd1` can only take input from a file name and not from standard input or when more than one input is needed like in `diff <(cmd1) <(cmd2)`.

There's no rlimit affecting it other than general ones like on the number of processes, cpu time or memory.

The PIPEBUF reported by some implementations of `ulimit` like `bash` and some implementations of `ksh` is not an rlimit but the maximum size for which a write to a pipe is guaranteed to be atomic so is irrelevant here. The size of the pipe itself (64kB on Linux as reported by @dsmsk80) is not really a limit itself. It just says that's as much `cmd2` can write to the pipe even after `cmd1` has stopped reading from it.

There's a limitation though in that `cmd1` may only *read* from that file. Because it's a pipe, it cannot write to that file or seek back and forth in the file.

`zsh` has a third form of command substitution using regular temporary files:

```
cmd1 =(cmd2)
```

calls `cmd1` with a temporary file which contains the output of `cmd2`. In that case `cmd1` is run *after* cmd2 instead of concurrently. The limit on the size of files may be reached there.

I don't know of any shell implementing a `<<<(...)` operator. There's however a `<<<` operator in `zsh` (inspired from the same operator in the Unix port of `rc`) also found in recent versions of `ksh93` and `bash`. It's a variation on the `<<` heredoc operator called herestring.

In:

```
cmd <<< something
```

Which is the same as the standard:

```
cmd << EOF
something
EOF
```

The shell creates a temporary file with `something\n` as the content and feeds that as standard input to a new process, unlinks that file and executes `cmd` in that new process. Again, that's a regular file so the rlimit on the maximum size of a file may be reached.

Now you can combine the `<<<` operator with `$(...)` (command substitution) to somehow emulate `zsh`'s `=(...)` operator in `bash` and `ksh93`:

```
cmd1 <<<"$(cmd2)"
```

Would run `cmd2` with it stdout redirected to a pipe. On the other end of the pipe, the shell reads the output of `cmd2` and stores it minus the trailing newline characters and with one newline character added into a temporary file and call `cmd1` with that temporary file open for reading as stdin (note there's another limitation in that it won't work if `cmd2` output contains NUL characters).

To be like `=(...)`, you'd have to write it:

```
cmd1 /dev/fd/3 3<<<"$(cmd3)"
```

Note the shell has to read the whole output of cmd3 in memory before writing it to the temporary file, so in addition to the maximum file size, you may also reach the limit on memory usage.

Also note that since version 5, `bash` strips the write permissions to the temporary file before calling `cmd1`, so if you need `cmd1` to be able to modify that file, you'd need to work around it with:

```
{
  chmod u+w /dev/fd/3 && # only needed in bash 5+
  cmd1 /dev/fd/3
} 3<<<"$(cmd3)"
```

Comment: But this does not seem to work: `ssh -F /dev/fd/3 default 3<<<"$(vagrant ssh-config)"`

Comment: @Sukima, see [Why doesn't the process substitution <() work with ssh -F](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/101900). ssh closes all its fds except 0, 1, 2 on startup.

Comment: Well that’s frustrating and disturbing. I wish unix programs all acted like unix programs sigh. Thanks for the article. I ended up having to do these four lines in a script file: `conf=“$(mktemp -t fix_moron_ssh)”; vagrant ssh-config >”$conf”; trap ‘rm -f “$conf”’ EXIT; exec ssh -F “$conf” default “$@“`.

Comment: @Sukima, `ssh` does it because (quoting from the code): _"Discard other fds that are hanging around. These can cause problem with backgrounded ssh processes started by ControlPersist"_. I'd agree it would be nicer if it only did it for the process hanging around to _persist_ the master connection. There are other commands like `sudo` where it makes a lot of sense to close all fds.